# Learning JavaBean

Tags: java

I am new in Java and I want to learn JavaBean from the scratch. So if someone can tell me something tutorial or link it would be of great help for me. 
And another question Can I use jsp action tags as sub-tag in Scriptlets?

Where could I find the generated servlet from the Jsp page ? I am using Tomcat 7.0.

Comment: Did you try in www.google.com? You will get plenty of tutorials for the same.

Comment: Actually I tried. But they are full of IDE based tutorial.I mean I need to clear my concepts.. so

Comment: try java by Herbert Schildt book for the basics on JavaBeans

Comment: @NiteshVerma Tried but it seemed insufficient.

Comment: @Aritit - you aren't in a position to decide if something is insufficient.  You don't know anything.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

There's a huge difference between Enterprise Java Beans (EJB) and Java Beans (Also referred to as POJOs'). The first one referrs to the business component part of the Enterprise Java Specification and there plenty of articles, guides, tutorials and other material out there on the internet discussing and explain

Answer (score 0):

The best tutorial is the [one from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/index.html).

You should not be adding scriptlet code to JSPs.  Learn JSTL and write scriptlet-free JSPs.

JSPs are an advanced topic, over and above Java Beans.  How does someone who doesn't know Java Beans write JSPs?

Comment: Exactly I knew someone would ask me a question like this..actually I know core Java moderately and now I am trying to shift to J2EE and while learning JSP i came across this Bean topic.. so first I want to learn Bean very well.

Comment: Btw, I was wondering is still alive technology and widely used?

Comment: Java Beans?  Of course it's alive and widely used.  Evidence?  Look at the number of SO questions pertaining to Java.